# How can I get the Apache AccessFileName value using PHP?

Tags: php, apache

I have a custom AccessFileName setup for my virtual host. How can I get that variable via code?

I've looked at the [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variables available but it doesn't have the AccessFileName listed as an available variable.

I do need to have this `AccessFileName` setting different for different virtual hosts so if I can do this without updating php.ini that would be ideal.

Comment: please be clear with your question

Comment: I've edited my question, more clear now?

Answer (score 0):

If you can add this option to virtualhost config, so you can add another one:

```
SetEnv ACCESS_FILE_NAME .another-name
```

And get it in php using `$_SERVER['ACCESS_FILE_NAME']`